# declaring a variable many times in the same code in Rcpp (C++)

Tags: c++, rcpp

For an R user who began using Rcpp, declaring variables is a new thing. My question is what actually happens when the same named variable is declared many times. In many examples, I see that index of for loops are declared each time.

```
cppFunction('
int add1( const int n ){
     int y = 0;
     for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
       for(int j=0; j<n; j++) y++;
       for(int j=0; j<(n*2); j++) y++;
     }
     return y ;
}
')
```

instead of

```
cppFunction('
int add2( const int n ){
     int y = 0;
     int i, j;
     for(i=0; i<n; i++){
       for(j=0; j<n; j++) y++;
       for(j=0; j<(n*2); j++) y++;
     }
     return y ;
}
')
```

Both seem to give the same answer. But is it generally ok to declare a variable (of the same name) many times in the same program? If it is not ok, when it is not ok? Or maybe I don't understand what 'declare' means, and e.g., the two functions above are identical (e.g., nothing is declared many times even in the first function).

Comment: please see below. I've added a post that examines the results of the compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is because of the encapsulation.
What you can try is

```
for(int i = 0; i<5;i++) {std::cout<<i<<std::endl; }
std::cout<<i<<std::endl;
```

this code does not work because "i" is only declared inside the for loop.
also if you have an "if-statement", every varable which is declared inside is encapsulated and does no longer exist outside the if statement.
The clamps { } also encapsulate variables.
What you can't do is

```
int i = 5;
int i = 4;
```

now you try to declare the same variable again, which gives you an error.

Answer (score 2):

## Overview

Alrighty, let's take a looksie at the assembly code after a compiler has transformed both statements. The compiler in this case should ideally provide the same optimization (we may want to run with the -O2 flag).

## Test Case

I've written up your file using pure C++. That is, I've opted to directly perform the compilation via terminal and not relying on `Rcpp` black magic which slips in `#include <Rcpp.h>` during every compilation.

**test.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>

int add2( const int n ){
     int y = 0;
     int i, j;
     for(i=0; i<n; i++){
       for(j=0; j<n; j++) y++;
       for(j=0; j<(n*2); j++) y++;
     }
     return y ;
}

int add1( const int n ){
     int y = 0;
     for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
       for(int j=0; j<n; j++) y++;
       for(int j=0; j<(n*2); j++) y++;
     }
     return y ;
}

int main(){

    std::cout << add1(2) << std::endl;

    std::cout << add2(2) << std::endl;
}
```

## Decomposing the Binary

To see how the C++ code was translated into assembly, I've opted to use `objdump` over the built in `otools` on macOS. (Someone is more than welcome to provide that output as well).

In macOS, I did:

```
gcc -g -c test.cpp
# brew install binutils # required for (g)objdump 
gobjdump -d -M intel -S test.o
```

This gives the following annotated output that I've chunked at the end of the post. In a nutshell, the assembly for both versions is exactly the same.

## Benchmarks are King

Another way to verify would be to do a simple microbenchmark. If there was significant difference between the two, that would provide evidence to suggest different optimizations.

```
# install.packages("microbenchmark")
library("microbenchmark")

microbenchmark(a = add1(100L), b = add2(100L))
```

Gives:

```
Unit: microseconds
 expr    min     lq     mean median      uq     max neval
    a 53.081 53.268 55.35613 53.576 53.8825  92.078   100
    b 53.069 53.261 56.28195 53.431 53.6795 169.841   100
```

Switching the order:

```
microbenchmark(b = add2(100L), a = add1(100L))
```

Gives:

```
Unit: microseconds
 expr    min      lq     mean  median      uq     max neval
    b 53.112 53.3215 60.14641 55.0575 60.7685 196.865   100
    a 53.130 53.6850 58.72041 55.2845 60.6005  93.401   100
```

In essence, the benchmarks themselves indicate no significant difference between either method.

## Appendix

### Long Output

#### Long output `add1`

```
int add1( const int n ){
  a0:   55                      push   rbp
  a1:   48 89 e5                mov    rbp,rsp
  a4:   89 7d fc                mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4],edi
     int y = 0;
  a7:   c7 45 f8 00 00 00 00    mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x8],0x0
     for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
  ae:   c7 45 f4 00 00 00 00    mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0xc],0x0
  b5:   8b 45 f4                mov    eax,DWORD PTR [rbp-0xc]
  b8:   3b 45 fc                cmp    eax,DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4]
  bb:   0f 8d 76 00 00 00       jge    137 <__Z4add1i+0x97>
       for(int j=0; j<n; j++) y++;
  c1:   c7 45 f0 00 00 00 00    mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x10],0x0
  c8:   8b 45 f0                mov    eax,DWORD PTR [rbp-0x10]
  cb:   3b 45 fc                cmp    eax,DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4]
  ce:   0f 8d 1b 00 00 00       jge    ef <__Z4add1i+0x4f>
  d4:   8b 45 f8                mov    eax,DWORD PTR [rbp-0x8]
  d7:   05 01 00 00 00          add    eax,0x1
  dc:   89 45 f8                mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x8],eax
  df:   8b 45 f0                mov    eax,DWORD PTR [rbp-0x10]
  e2:   05 01 00 00 00          add    eax,0x1
  e7:   89 45 f0                mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x10],eax
  ea:   e9 d9 ff ff ff          jmp    c8 <__Z4add1i+0x28>
       for(int j=0; j<(n*2); j++) y++;
  ef:   c7 45 ec 00 00 00 00    mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x14],0x0
  f6:   8b 45 ec                mov    eax,DWORD PTR [rbp-0x14]
  f9:   8b 4d fc                mov    ecx,DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4]
  fc:   c1 e1 01                shl    ecx,0x1
  ff:   39 c8                   cmp    eax,ecx
 101:   0f 8d 1b 00 00 00       jge    122 <__Z4add1i+0x82>
 107:   8b 45 f8                mov    eax,DWORD PTR [rbp-0x8]
 10a:   05 01 00 00 00          add    eax,0x1
 10f:   89 45 f8                mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x8],eax
 112:   8b 45 ec                mov    eax,DWORD PTR [rbp-0x14]
 115:   05 01 00 00 00          add    eax,0x1
 11a:   89 45 ec                mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x14],eax
 11d:   e9 d4 ff ff ff          jmp    f6 <__Z4add1i+0x56>
     }
 122:   e9 00 00 00 00          jmp    127 <__Z4add1i+0x87>
     return y ;
}
```

#### Long Output for `add2`

```
int add2( const int n ){
   0:   55                      push   rbp
   1:   48 89 e5                mov    rbp,rsp
   4:   89 7d fc                mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4],edi
     int y = 0;
   7:   c7 45 f8 00 00 00 00    mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x8],0x0
     int i, j;
     for(i=0; i<n; i++){
   e:   c7 45 f4 00 00 00 00    mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0xc],0x0
  15:   8b 45 f4                mov    eax,DWORD PTR [rbp-0xc]
  18:   3b 45 fc                cmp    eax,DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4]
  1b:   0f 8d 76 00 00 00       jge    97 <__Z4add2i+0x97>
       for(j=0; j<n; j++) y++;
  21:   c7 45 f0 00 00 00 00    mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x10],0x0
  28:   8b 45 f0                mov    eax,DWORD PTR [rbp-0x10]
  2b:   3b 45 fc                cmp    eax,DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4]
  2e:   0f 8d 1b 00 00 00       jge    4f <__Z4add2i+0x4f>
  34:   8b 45 f8                mov    eax,DWORD PTR [rbp-0x8]
  37:   05 01 00 00 00          add    eax,0x1
  3c:   89 45 f8                mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x8],eax
  3f:   8b 45 f0                mov    eax,DWORD PTR [rbp-0x10]
  42:   05 01 00 00 00          add    eax,0x1
  47:   89 45 f0                mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x10],eax
  4a:   e9 d9 ff ff ff          jmp    28 <__Z4add2i+0x28>
       for(j=0; j<(n*2); j++) y++;
  4f:   c7 45 f0 00 00 00 00    mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x10],0x0
  56:   8b 45 f0                mov    eax,DWORD PTR [rbp-0x10]
  59:   8b 4d fc                mov    ecx,DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4]
  5c:   c1 e1 01                shl    ecx,0x1
  5f:   39 c8                   cmp    eax,ecx
  61:   0f 8d 1b 00 00 00       jge    82 <__Z4add2i+0x82>
  67:   8b 45 f8                mov    eax,DWORD PTR [rbp-0x8]
  6a:   05 01 00 00 00          add    eax,0x1
  6f:   89 45 f8                mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x8],eax
  72:   8b 45 f0                mov    eax,DWORD PTR [rbp-0x10]
  75:   05 01 00 00 00          add    eax,0x1
  7a:   89 45 f0                mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x10],eax
  7d:   e9 d4 ff ff ff          jmp    56 <__Z4add2i+0x56>
     }
  82:   e9 00 00 00 00          jmp    87 <__Z4add2i+0x87>
```

### Output short output

#### Short output for `add1`

```
int add1( const int n ){
     int y = 0;
     for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
 127:   8b 45 f4                mov    eax,DWORD PTR [rbp-0xc]
 12a:   05 01 00 00 00          add    eax,0x1
 12f:   89 45 f4                mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0xc],eax
 132:   e9 7e ff ff ff          jmp    b5 <__Z4add1i+0x15>
       for(int j=0; j<n; j++) y++;
       for(int j=0; j<(n*2); j++) y++;
     }
     return y ;
 137:   8b 45 f8                mov    eax,DWORD PTR [rbp-0x8]
 13a:   5d                      pop    rbp
 13b:   c3                      ret    
 13c:   0f 1f 40 00             nop    DWORD PTR [rax+0x0]

0000000000000140 <_main>:
}
```

#### Short output for `add2`

```
int add2( const int n ){
     int y = 0;
     int i, j;
     for(i=0; i<n; i++){
  87:   8b 45 f4                mov    eax,DWORD PTR [rbp-0xc]
  8a:   05 01 00 00 00          add    eax,0x1
  8f:   89 45 f4                mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0xc],eax
  92:   e9 7e ff ff ff          jmp    15 <__Z4add2i+0x15>
       for(j=0; j<n; j++) y++;
       for(j=0; j<(n*2); j++) y++;
     }
     return y ;
  97:   8b 45 f8                mov    eax,DWORD PTR [rbp-0x8]
  9a:   5d                      pop    rbp
  9b:   c3                      ret    
  9c:   0f 1f 40 00             nop    DWORD PTR [rax+0x0]

00000000000000a0 <__Z4add1i>:
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the 2 examples you give, it will not make much difference which one you choose - the compiler is almost certain to optimise them identically.

Both are perfectly legal. The second case you cite is fine because each variable is contained to the scope of the for loop.

Personally, I will always write my loops like in your second example unless the index of the loop is related to some other pre-existing variable. I think this is a neater solution and complies with the idea of declaring variables where you need them.

C/C++ will allow you to do something which is not completely intuitive - it will allow you to redefine the same variable name in a nested scope and then things can start to get messy:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    for (int i = 10; i < 100; i++) {
        // Be careful what you do here!  
    }
}
```

In the inner loop any reference to 'i' will refer to the 'i' declared in the inner loop - the outer loop 'i' is now inaccessible. I have seen so many bugs based on this and they can be hard to spot because it is almost never a deliberate choice by the programmer.